# Update sepcific line in file

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi is there a method from which I can update a specific line in a file.
My file has data seperated by line break

Sample example to delete line but I have to write everything into file again, can I perform CRUD opertion directly on file lines ?

I want to update specific line in file wihout reading entire file => update string and => write all lines to file.

I may switch to any kind of file type that can offer me this functionality.
Is there a way to store data in row column architecture like sql ?

```
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> myAsyncFunction() async {
  const index = 5;
  final File f = File('test.txt');
  final List<String> lines = await f.readAsLines();
  lines.removeAt(index);
  await f.writeAsString(lines.join('\n'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by using the [String Scanner](https://pub.dev/documentation/string_scanner/latest/string_scanner/LineScanner-class.html) library, it provides a class called `LineScanner` and `LineScannerState` through which you can set the position.

I have not tried this for the exact use case you mention above, so please do evaluate it for your use-case

Answer (score 1):

Files are stored as a contiguous array of bytes on a disk, there is no way to remove a specific line without scanning for newlines and shifting trailing data to fill the void.

For a more sophisticated way of storing data there are many popular database packages, including [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite), [hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive), [drift](https://pub.dev/packages/drift), [sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast), and [objectbox](https://pub.dev/packages/objectbox).